# Fastest way to check if proxy server is working Python

Tags: python, proxy

I'm trying to make a program that checks whether or not a proxy is working.

```py
import requests

def check_proxy(proxy: str):
    proxies = {
        "http": f"http://{proxy}",
        "https": f"http://{proxy}"
    }

    try:
        requests.get("https://google.com/", proxies=proxies)
        return True

    except:
        return False
```

But it is excruciatingly slow, is there a way I can do this any faster without changing the timeout? And if there isn't what's the best possible time for the timeout?

Comment: Use multiple threads.

Comment: "is there a way I can do this any faster without changing the timeout? " Well, no; the *reason* it's slow is that it will keep trying to use a non-working proxy until the timeout is reached. That's what the timeout value is *for*.